# Como puedo mostrar un valor de un select html en vivo

Tags: php, jquery

Ejemplo

```
<select id="selectid">
    <option value="1">Primera opción</option>
    <option value="2">Segunda opción</option>
    <option value="3">Tercera opción</option>
</select>

<?php
     echo imprime el valor
```

si escojo  1 en el html debe mostrar 1 , y así. que no sea por metodo post o get solo mostrarlo ,

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Para hacer lo que deseas necesitas usar Javascript. Si muestras algo de código de lo que lleves intentado seguro que se te podrá ayudar.

Comment: me dijeron que use jquery, solo imprimir el valor obtenido del selected

Comment: `$("#selectid").on("change", function(){alert($( "#selectid" ).val();)})`

Comment: Gracias, ya me salio.

Comment: @AlejandroEdwardAvendaoPrinc Pon el código de cómo lo has resuelto en una "Respuesta"

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas hacer, debes hacerlo directamente por javascript.

```js
$("#selectid").on("change", function() {
  $("#valorSelectid").html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<div id="valorSelectid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectid").change(function(){
            var idSelected= $(this).val();
            console.log(idSelected);

        });
```

con esto te imprimirá en consola el valor asignado del value.

Comment: No es solo escribir código, es explicar por qué soluciona el problema planteado y lo que hace.